# Practice Exercise on tidyr Functions

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Using the first.df data frame, separate the DoB column data into 3 new columns - date, month,year by using the separate() function.I tried last line but it is not giving desired result.

```
fname <- c("Martina", "Monica", "Stan", "Oscar")
lname <- c("Welch", "Sobers", "Griffith", "Williams")
DoB <- c("1-Oct-1980", "2-Nov-1982", "13-Dec-1979", "27-Jan-1988")

first.df <- data.frame(fname,lname,DoB)
print(first.df)

separate(first.df,DoB,c('date','month','year'),sep = '-')
```

Comment: What's wrong with your result? I ran your code on my machine and it looks correct.

Comment: date should contain DoB value not the day

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you load `tidyr` and that no other `separate` function is loaded. "Not giving desired result" is not helpful at all... 1. What is the desired result? 2. What are you getting?

Comment: Try this: `separate(first.df,DoB,c(NA,'month','year'),sep = '-', remove=FALSE)`

Comment: yes, it is working @CaioBrighenti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved my comment to an actual answer.

To retain the date column you need to add the `remove = FALSE` parameter, and to discard one of the separated columns simply add `NA` instead of a column name. The correct command is then

`separate(first.df,DoB,c(NA,'month','year'),sep = '-', remove=FALSE)`